# Prestashop webservice specific_prices problem

Tags: php, api, web-services, prestashop

I'm trying to add a specific price with web services, but it gives me an error. Why?

> ERROR: This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an
> HTTP status of 500.

```
try {
    $webService = $this->connPS();
    $opt = array('resource' => 'specific_prices');
    $xml = $webService->get(array(
        'url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/specific_prices?schema=blank'));
    $product = $xml->children()->children();

    unset($product->id);
    $product->id_shop = 1;
    $product->id_cart = 0;
    $product->id_product = 553;
    $product->id_currency = 0;
    $product->id_country = 0;
    $product->id_group = 0;
    $product->id_customer = 0;
    $product->id_shop_group = 0;
    $product->id_product_attribute = 0;
    $product->id_specific_price_rule = 0;
    $product->reduction = 1;
    $product->reduction_tax = 1;
    $product->reduction_type = 'amount';
    $product->price = -1;
    $product->from_quantity = 1;
    $product->from = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    $product->to = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";

    $opt = array('resource' => 'specific_prices');
    $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
    $xml = $webService->add($opt);
    $product_price = $xml->specific_prices;
} catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e) {
    // Here we are dealing with errors
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) {
        return 'Bad ID';
    } else {
        if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) {
            return 'Bad auth key';
        } else {
            return '<b>ERROR:</b> '.$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XML result:

```html
[resource] => specific_prices
    [postXml] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<specific_price>
    
    <id_shop_group>0</id_shop_group>
    <id_shop>1</id_shop>
    <id_cart>0</id_cart>
    <id_product>594</id_product>
    <id_product_attribute>0</id_product_attribute>
    <id_currency>0</id_currency>
    <id_country>0</id_country>
    <id_group>0</id_group>
    <id_customer>0</id_customer>
    <id_specific_price_rule>0</id_specific_price_rule>
    <price>-1</price>
    <from_quantity>1</from_quantity>
    <reduction>0.2</reduction>
    <reduction_tax>1</reduction_tax>
    <reduction_type>percentage</reduction_type>
    <from>0000-00-00</from>
    <to>0000-00-00</to>
</specific_price>
</prestashop>
```

The XML result seems ok, but the web service does not give me any information about the error. Could someone help me?

Comment: What's the error on webserver error_log ? Also have you tried enabling Prestashop dev_mode and check the response again to see if anything useful about the error is getting printed in the response ?

Comment: Enabling dev_mode this is the error: `ERROR: HTTP XML response is not parsable: array ( 0 => LibXMLError::__set_state(array( 'level' => 3, 'code' => 5, 'column' => 1, 'message' => 'Extra content at the end of the document ', 'file' => '', 'line' => 2, )), )`

Comment: @user3256843 you must use this script with an active product... my test was with a disabled product. all work fine. thanks, best regards!